# How to persist selection on React using mui-datatable

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I'm using mui-datatable to implement table in my app. I've every feature I need up and running, and I'm using server side data and pagination.

The problem is that I need to persist selection of rows when the user change the current page.

I can store the ids of the rows that where selected in an external array using onRowSelected.. but I'm not sure how to make the table render those rows as selected when user changes the page.

Bare in mind i'm using server side data, so the idea would be that in page 1, when I select row 1, a take the id of that record and add it to the array of selected ids. Then I need to check if the ids of rows that are currently displayed in the page are included in the selected array, and if so then check it as selected in the table. That way when I change the page, the same logic would run and all rows would be cleared since none of the row in the new page are selected.. I think you get the point.

I dont know where should i check if the row's id is included y my selected array and if so, how to check it in the datatable.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you looked at Reacts useState hook? You could store the IDs in state and reference it whenever you like, clear it whenever you need etc.

Comment: @AlexGilliott Hi!... thanks, yes I could use useState, but that's not the issue... I'm storing the selection, whether I do it using a class component state or useState hook doesnt matter... what I need to know is how to tell mui-datatables which rows should be selected and which shouldn't everytime the table changes page.. Since I'm passing server side data in chunks to the table I'm looking for some sort of "onRowRendered" event that allows me to check if the row being rendered is in my selection or not, and make the table check the check box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid... I just needed some sleep xD

My problem was solved once I realized that I just needed to pass the rowsSelected option like this:

```
rowsSelected: this.state.pictures.filter(p=>this.state.selectedIds.includes(p.id)).map((p,i)=>i)
```

where this.state.picture will change when the user changes the page and rowsSelected will also changed.

Never mind... It's a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your entire MUI datatable in another component which maintains the state of all selected rows